# To read excel group rows data using UiPath

Tags: excel, uipath-studio

Read an excel contains 4 columns. member name, age, amount and status
Read excel and group all the rows with status as completed
Group all rows with status as error
Create two tabs in the same sheet as error and completed
write the above group of rows to corresponding tabs and save the excel

Comment: Please be clear what the question / problem is. Also try to use more punctuation markers.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really unclear, so no idea if this answer is what you are looking for.

I'm assuming what you want is to split your original table into two sheets, Sheet 1 for Complete and Sheet 2 for Errors.

Start a new 'Excel Application Scope'
Read Range (for your current spreadsheet) and set the output DT Variable. (For this example will call it dt_Results)

Use the For Each Row Activity and set the dt_Results.

[image]

Use the Add Data Row - set Datarow as 'row' and call one of them dt_Completed and the other dt_Error

This will then create the two new DataTables which you will then use to write to your new file:

[image]